# Why does the Java collections APIs not have a last method?

Tags: java, api-design

This is for ordered collections e.g. java.util.List. Why did the language designers not include a last method? The only reasons I can think of are:

- ambiguity when the collection is empty (return null or throw exception)
- API bloat

Any other reasons?

Comment: +1 for the sheer number of times that I've had to write `collection.get(collection.size() - 1)`.

Comment: Why not write your own utility class that has this method, and any other method you might want to use with collections?

Comment: There isn't a first() method either, so why should there be a last() method?

Comment: @Peter: You can get the first element easily through `get(0)` and it is short and easy to understand. Getting the last element through `get(size() - 1)` is rather annoying. Contrast with Python, where getting the last element is done through the equivalent of `get(-1)`.

Comment: @Peter urgh the only thing worse than not implementing getLast() is implementing it with a hack like get(-1).

Comment: @Alb I guess "hack" is in the eye of the beholder :) At this point in time, I appreciate python's -1 syntax. Of course, if you ask me again sometime in the future or in the past, I may feel exactly as you do.

Comment: @Alb Using negative indexes is more powerful than a `last()` method, since you can get the nth-to-last element just as easily with `get(-2)`, `get(-3)`, etc. I wouldn't call it a hack.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

API bloat is probably the answer. From my experience the only time I've needed this functionality a Queue or Stack was the correct data structure for the job having the appropriate method.

Comment: Guess you are partially correct, but if Java supported `get(-1)` to retrieve from the end of a list it would do what the OP wanted without adding API bloat.  My answer as such has drawn unexplained downvotes.

Comment: I think a bigger answer is that Java's initial failure (repeated in .NET, and still ongoing in the latter case) to support default interface methods meant that having interfaces include a member which 99% of implementations would handle the same way would impose extra work on *all* implementations for the benefit of the few that would implement them differently.

Answer (score 16):

a `last()` method is just as easy as `list.get(list.size()-1)`, just like there is no `first()` method or `fifth()` method. It isn't that hard to synthesize and is a specialization. You can also `reverse()` the list and `list.get(0)` which will give the `last` item. Things that are easy to do, usually don't get their own specialized methods.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();

        l.add("A");
        l.add("B");
        l.add("Z");

        System.out.println("l.get(0) = " + l.get(0));
        System.out.println("l.get(l.size()-1) = " + l.get(l.size() - 1));
    }
}
```

results in the following output

```
l.get(0) = A
l.get(l.size()-1) = Z
```

it is also presumptuous to assume that everything that implements the `List` interface actually has the concept of `last()` anything.

Comment: It would be clearer in both cases though

Comment: Note that the size() method may not be able to answer if the collection is not yet fully populated.

Comment: `.size()` will return the current size `.size()-1` will still be the last element regardless, how would it know if it was fully populated or not?

Comment: By the specification, a List can contain more than Integer.MAX_VALUE elements, in which case size() returns Integer.MAX_VALUE, so `.size()-1` is not the perfect way to implement `last()` (though such a large list is very unlikely and I wonder how such a list would implement `toArray()`...)

Comment: C# does have a .First & .Last method. Reversing a list just to get the last item isn't exactly efficient either.

Comment: reversing a list can be almost free depending on the implementation of the list, to assume it *isn't exactly efficient* shows a lack of comprehension between the concept of `List` as an `Interface` and the implementations of that interface.

Answer (score 5):

The `java.util.LinkedList` defines the `getLast()` and `getFirst()` methods. Unfortunately these methods are not defined in one of it's interfaces, so you have to use the LinkedList type. If you are only interested in the last element you might consider to use the `java.util.Queue` interface's `peek()` method. LinkedList implements Queue.

Comment: This is not really correct. Just like the `Queue`, the `LinkedList` class implements the `Deque` interface that has the methods `peek()`, `peekFirst()` and `peekLast()`. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Deque.html

Answer (score -1):

Basically you either have to ask for the `size()` for a `for`-loop or iterate it by asking for its iterator and use it in a while or do-loop.  Use the one suitable for your purpose.

The iterator knows at a given point if there are more entries and allows you to get the next one if there is.  You then repeat until "more entries?" fails.

See the "Traversing Collections" section at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. It is also extremely inefficient to use an iterator to find the last element in a list.